Cocoapods - Does pod install --clean-install ignore the Podfile.lock file?
QQ: Does pod install --clean-install ignore the Podfile.lock file? The documentation is unclear.
--clean-install
Ignore the contents of the project cache and force a full pod installation. This only applies to projects that have enabled incremental installation.
ref: https://guides.cocoapods.org/terminal/commands.html#pod_install

No, the documentation says that it will ignore the cache which means it will download pod from Remote instead of using cache from your machine.
If you want to ignore the Podfile.lock file then just rename it (may be Podfile1.lock) or remove it and run pod install.

How can you be sure the Podfile.lock file is being respected? There is also a --deployment flag which, also, leads me to believe if it is not provided it may ignore the Podfile.lock:
`--deployment
Disallow any changes to the Podfile or the Podfile.lock during installation.`
